# Python os.dup and side-effects

Tags: python, linux, system, pipe

At the beginning of my python script I do:

```
if '-' in args:
  fd = os.fdopen(os.dup(0))
  sys.stderr.write(fd.read())
  fd.close()
```

I thought that this wouldn't affect the behavior of the rest of my program but it seems to, i.e. if I comment out these 4 lines my code works but if they are executed then my program has unexpected results (which I'm having difficulty troubleshooting).

Am I using os.dup incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is incomplete without describing the "unexpected results" which you're having difficulty troubleshooting.

Comment: I have seen this pattern before! He is trying to peek at what his input is but without “using it up” before the rest of his program can read it in. Shall I admit that, in my own Unix youth, I myself tried this once before realizing that *file descriptors* and *actual files* are two quite different things? :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not, alas, using `os.dup()` correctly. Evidently you want to “look ahead” in the Standard Input stream to see what will be there, and print it out, but then have the rest of the program start up and see the same input still sitting there waiting on the Standard Input. (Is my guess correct that you are doing this for debugging purposes?)

The problem with your approach is that running `os.dup()` simply creates a second file *descriptor*, not a second *file* — in other words, it creates another integer with which you can refer to the source of your input data, but `dup()` does not create a second actual source of data. So whether you `read()` from the first file descriptor or the second one, you have still “used up” all of the data from your input stream.

Answer (score 0):

I also am not sure about the correct usage of `os.dup()`, but for your example you could do

```
if '-' in args:
    sys.stderr.write(sys.stdin.read())
```

or even

```
    print(input())  # for python 2.x it would be print raw_input()
```